# Get attribute from actionlink to jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

How can I get an attribute from an `actionlink` to jquery?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit contact", "Edit", "Contact", new { Area = "Customers", contactId = -1 }, new { @id="EditContact", @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

I wish to dynamically update the `contactId` when I press a contact.

```
$(document).on('click', '#contacts .list-group-item', function(e) {
        var id = (this.id);
        var elem = $('#EditContact');
        var newUrl = elem.prop('href').replace('-1', id);
        elem.prop('href', newUrl);
    });
```

This code works, but just for one time because the -1 changes. So I need to collect the `contactId` and save it as a variable.

```
$(document).on('click', '#contacts .list-group-item', function(e) {
                var id = (this.id);
                var elem = $('#EditContact');
                var oldId = elem.attr('contactId');
                var newUrl = elem.prop('href').replace('oldId', id);
                elem.prop('href', newUrl);
    });
```

I have tried this, but the `oldId` is undefined. How can I collect the `contactId`?

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is, instead of keeping -1 as the route value, just generate the link without the route value(s). So it will be just the base url (without querystring for the contactId). When the link is clicked, you can use this base url and append the id and generate the new url and navigate to that.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit contact", "Edit", "Contact", new { Area = "Customers" }, 
                                        new { @id="EditContact", @class = "btn btn-info" })
```

And in the click event make sure to prevent the default click event behavior.

```
$(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '.list-group-item', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = (this.id);
        var newUrl = $('#EditContact').attr("href") + '?contactId=' + id;
        window.location.href = newUrl;
    });    

});
```

Another **better solution** is, when you build the items with class "list-group-item" in the loop, you can add a data attribute for the url.

For example

```
@foreach(var item in SomeCollection)
{
  <div class="list-group-item" data-url="@Url.Action("Edit", "Contact",
                                            new { Area = "Customers" ,contactId=item .Id})">
       Some Name of the Item in the loop
  </div>
}
```

and now, when this is clicked, read the url data property and use that for navigation.

```
$(function () {

    $(document).on('click', '.list-group-item', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();           
        window.location.href = $(this).data("url");
    });    

});
```

Comment: In your first solution you are appending the `?contactId` part to the `href` attribute. When another list item is clicked, you will append this again, which will result in an invalid URL. But your second solution is correct :)

Comment: No. I am appending the contactId and it's value to the base url (Which does not have the contact id in the url( i did not pass contact id in the route values) and i am not updating the link's href value with this new url. It stays the same (the base url without contact id query string). So it should still work.

Comment: My bad, you are right. This works since you are setting the `window.location.href`, I've read over that part. But still, OP is *setting* the `href` of it's html element in his question example. So it would be better to *store* the base url in some `data-*` attribute, for example in his edit action link.